# how to get started with PCM?

Tags: c++, intel, performancecounter

I wanted to work on Intel PCM. I follwed the below link:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor

I downloaded the code, i started to study example pcm.cpp. But Im not getting any proper understanding. Documentation is not that much clear.

http://intel-pcm-api-documentation.github.io/classPCM.html

I tried to run , pcm.x ,it gave basic information then showed some error like:

"Trying to use Linux perf events...
Linux Perf: Error on programming generic event #0 error: Invalid argument
Access to Intel(r) Performance Counter Monitor has denied (**Unknown error**)."

Unknown error! I cant figure out why its not accessible. I used with sudo also(root privileges).

Any suggestions how I can start working with it? Where to start?

Comment: Are you running inside a virtual machine?  Normally Linux allows unprivileged processes to user perf counters.  [`ocperf.py` is nice](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/blob/master/ocperf.py): it's a wrapper around `perf` that has symbolic names for more uarch-specific perf counters:

Comment: suggest you post on Intel forum https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. 
I am not using VM, using Ubuntu 14.04. rdmsr and wrmsr are working which means i have privileges right!!

How that python script is helpful??
When i try to run i got the error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anthony/Downloads/IntelPerformanceCounterMonitor-PCM-V2.10/test.py", line 52, in <module>
    from pmudef import *
ImportError: No module named pmudef"

Comment: @codecats: Thanks 
I have already gone through that link. I dint get any good information.

Comment: ocperf.py doesn't help for using the Intel PCM library (or whatever it is).  It *does* help for using the existing Linux `perf` command-line frontend for accessing the same hardware performance counters through the `perf` API that's part of the standard kernel.  Try running `perf stat /bin/true` to see if `perf` works normally on your system.  If it does, but Intel's software doesn't, it might need its own kernel module (which you'd need to load).

Comment: @Peter: Oh..Thanks.. "perf stat /bin/true" works fine in my system. 
1)Do perf offers to change MSR registers like PCM??
2)Can you specify how can I use that Python file with perf tool?

Comment: I happened to see a mention (while reading something else) that Intel's PCM needs to run as root, for some reason.  `ocperf.py` is a wrapper around `perf`.  You install it, and then run `ocperf.py stat /bin/true` or whatever.  See [the web site](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/).  Using the `perf` API from your own programs (modifying the MSRs on the fly) is problematic, since apparently the internals aren't well documented.  http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/faq.html#q2b.  I usually just put the loop I want to time in a tiny program by itself, and `perf stat` it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/590239) by Roman Dementiev that worked for me:

> As a workaround you can disable perf usage in the PCM Makefile by removing "-DPCM_USE_PERF".